# In Measure theory,What is meaning when a function is not integrable?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

In the textbook "Foundations of Modern Analysis (by Avner Friedman)",f is integrable if there exists a sequence of simple integrable function ${f_{n}}$ such that 
(a)$f_{n} \rightarrow f  $ in mean.
(b)$f_{n} \rightarrow f  $ a.e.
(c)$\int f=lim\int f_{n}$.
$\color{blue}{My\quad question\quad1}$ :It is a concise definition,but hidden much information.Such as,What is meaning when a function is not integrable?Is it the follwing cases where f is not integrale?
case1: you cant find out a sequence of simple integrable function,How can you determine whether a sequence of simple integrable functions exists?
case2:you can find out a sequence of simple integrable function,but it doesn't satisfy (a) or (b),Is it meaning that the limt (c) is oscillation or equal to $+ \infty $ or $- \infty $，I have read other definition of integrable function,$\int f= \int f^{+}- \int f^{-}$,f is not integrable if $ \int f^{+}=\infty \quad or \int f^{-}=\infty$.Is it equivalent between the two definition?
$\color{blue}{My\quad question\quad2}$:it is hard to say some function is integrable even though the function is very easy.Such as,prove for any n$,f_{n}  $ is integrable,

\begin{equation}
f_{n} (x)= 
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        \frac{1}{x}, & \text{if }\frac{1}{n}\le x\le1\\
        0, & \text{if } x=0
    \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
you konw,according the definition,you need out find simple integrable function for every $f_{n}  $,it is difficult.

Comment: They are equivalent. For showing that a given function is integrable using the first defitnion just use the standard construction found in nay book on Measure Theory.

Comment: My guess is (for question 1 case 2) that for this definition, we assume $f$ to be $\ge0$